# What are appropriate actions when particular linux project seems dead?

Tags: collaboration, ownership, software-development

It seems no one reads email list, bugs and the last commit was in 2015. At the same time, the project is heavily used.

What would be the appropriate action to find new company to maintain the project?

Comment: Are you asking how you can maintain it yourself, or how you can find someone else to do the work of maintaining it for free?

Comment: As I said, the project is heavily used, so I think companies that relate them most should put some employees on it.

Comment: If they thought there was a **business** reason to do that, they would likely already have done so.  Businesses don't, generally, feel gratitude, so expecting them to act against their own interest out of gratitude is likely to fail.  OpenPGP, which is used by nearly everyone (though many of them don't know it) so failed to get funding that the project lead had to [threaten to quit](https://it.slashdot.org/story/15/02/05/2243258/gpg-programmer-werner-koch-is-running-out-of-money) before any real support was offered.

Comment: The project I meant is OpenDKIM. It has been used by Postfix to sign electronic mails and it is a suggested by the biggest email receiver, Google, to sign emails with  dkim: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en  

But the sole maintainer of the project doesn't have time for it any more (or whatever reason). I think Google shall take over project maintenance to increase quality of Gmail product. Or some foundation...

Comment: It's difficult coming to someone and telling him/her/it to do *whatever* when there is nothing you (can) offer. Try asking them whether they actually *do* have a private(?) repo with additional commits of it which they might care to share. Don't expect a reply, though

Comment: Are you asking about a Linux project (e.g. device drivers or kernel improvement), or are you asking about some software that coincidentally runs on Gnu/Linux?

Comment: coincidentally runs... OpenDKIM